# Convert PHP short tags In Sublime Text 3 (ST3)?

Tags: php, sublimetext3

Is there a Sublime Text 3 (ST3) plugin which converts PHP short tags like `<?` and `<?=` to their respective (more appropriate) `<?php` and `<?php echo` equivalents?

Seems like that would be overkill for a plugin if that were all it did, but I haven't found one which does this yet.

Bonus points if it adds semi-colons to ends of lines if they don't exist, even in spaghetti code.

Comment: Doesn't it have Search & Replace across multiple files?

Comment: why dont you multiselect those tags and replace it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace all `<?` and `<?=` in a project with the following steps:

- Drag and drop the folder containing your project into ST3.
- `Ctrl + Shift + f` to find and replace words in all files in your project

If some files contain `<?php` instead of `<?`, doing the replacement will result in a wrong syntax: `<?phpphp`

So in order to handle this problem, ST3 allow you to find using regex (by clicking on the `[]` symbol in the search bar). Therefore you can use the following expression to find only `<?`

```
<\?( |\n)
```

Comment: It makes sense to mention that `<?` substring matches the first 2 characters in `<?php`. So one must think of a better criteria to not break the code

Comment: I'll modify my answer to fit this case

Comment: Just adding the space at the end of find and replace strings would do the trick though, or doing it in a certain order.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this:

1. replace `<?=` to `<?php echo`
2. then replace `<?` to `<?php`
3. then replace `<?phpphp` to `<?php`